# Resizing and updating image in Django

Tags: django, django-models, django-admin, sorl-thumbnail

I'm overriding my save method because I want to resize my image. My problem is obvious in this code, what happens after I save my data is that django starts an endless loop. Of course is because I'm checking if self.vertical is set or not (and is always set). Save method is always called.

I could solve this problem checking if my self.id is none, but the code will work only for new entries, if the user tries to update, nothing changes because the id is not null.

I also tried to pop an false argument to kwargs and after saving, set true, but also didnt work. Someone has an idea how can I solve this?

PS: get_thumbnail is a method of sorl thumbnail plugin.

```
    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        if self.vertical_poster: 
            super(Movie, self).save(*args, **kwargs)

            resized_vertical = get_thumbnail(self.vertical_poster, "155x240", quality=99)            

            #save the new resized file            
            self.vertical_poster.save(resized_vertical.name, ContentFile(resized_vertical.read()), True)

         super(Movie, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Any idea or sample code will be appreciated! Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My solution was not override my save method. I did something different:

I decided to use "django-resized". This plugin is compatible with "sorl-thumbnail" and resizes image origin to specified size on the model field, as below:

```
from django_resized import ResizedImageField

class Movie(models.Model):

    ....

    vertical_poster = ResizedImageField(upload_to="movies", width=155, height=240)
```

I hope that can help other people.

Link: https://github.com/un1t/django-resized

Answer (score 0):

You can check the image whether it is already in your desired dimensions. I think you can use https://pypi.python.org/pypi/dimensions to make it simple

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.vertical_poster: 
        import dimensions

        # Set desired dimensions
        width = 155
        height = 240

        image_info = dimensions.dimensions(self.vertical_poster)

        if image_info[0] != width and image_info[1] != height:
            dimension = '%dx%d' % (width, height)
            resized_vertical = get_thumbnail(self.vertical_poster, dimension, quality=99)            

            #save the new resized file            
            self.vertical_poster.save(resized_vertical.name, ContentFile(resized_vertical.read()), True)
    super(Movie, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Hope it helps.

Comment: Hey, thanks for tha answer. Anyway, I could do this but get_thumbnail doesn't resize the image with the exactly size. It always depends...

Comment: I see, so where exactly are you getting the dimensions for resizing?

Answer (score 0):

If you use ImageField you can do it like this:

```
def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
    if self.vertical_poster.x != 155 or self.vertical_poster.y != 240:
        resized_vertical = get_thumbnail(self.vertical_poster, "155x240", quality=99)            

        # save the new resized file            
        self.vertical_poster.save(resized_vertical.name, ContentFile(resized_vertical.read()), True)

     super(Movie, self).save(*args, **kwargs)
```

Comment: Hey, thanks for tha answer. Anyway, I could do this but get_thumbnail doesn't resize the image with the exactly size. It always depends...

Answer (score 0):

You can create a mixin and use wherever you want likewise.

mixins.py

```
from io import BytesIO
from PIL import Image


class ShrinkImageMixin:

    def shrink_image(self, field_name, resize_shape):
        img: Image = Image.open(getattr(self, field_name))
        img.thumbnail(self.get_shrinked_size(field_name, resize_shape), Image.ANTIALIAS)
        image_file = BytesIO()
        img.save(image_file, 'jpg')
        getattr(self, field_name).file = image_file

    def get_shrinked_size(self, field_name, resize_shape):
        actual_img_width, actual_img_height = getattr(self, field_name).width, getattr(self, field_name).height
        ratio = min(resize_shape[0] / actual_img_width, resize_shape[1] / actual_img_height)
        return int(actual_img_width * ratio), int(actual_img_height * ratio)
```

models.py

```
from .mixins import ShrinkImageMixin

class Article(ShrinkImageMixin, models.Model):

    ...

    background_image = models.ImageField()

    ...

    def save(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self.shrink_image('background_image', (750, 375))
        super(Article, self).save()
```

This will shrink your image down to your desired size maintaining the aspect ratio. You just need to provide the image field name in the model and resize_shpe tuple.